# What does "andaba borracho" mean in this sentence

Tags: traducción

I'm just beginning to learn Spanish and I came across a line from the song "*No te contaron mal*" that I don't quite understand. The line goes

> Si andaba borracho era culpa tuya

why is it "Si andaba borracho..." and not "Si estaba borracho" in this case? Does andar have a different meaning? Or when talking about intoxication do we use andar?

Estoy aprendiendo español y no entiendo esta oración

> Si andaba borracho era culpa tuya

¿Por qué él cantante usó andar y no usó estaba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Andar" can also mean "estar" (in a given situation). The DLE says:

> **4.** intr. Estar o encontrarse en determinado estado o situación.

I think "andar" is typically used to refer to refer to longer time spans. For instance, "estaba borracho" is usually understood as "I was drunk at that specific time", whereas "andaba borracho" is typically taken to mean "I was usually drunk". This is a subtle difference, and it isn't applied consistently.

Therefore,

> Si estaba borracho era culpa tuya.

and

> Si andaba borracho era culpa tuya.

mean roughly the same thing (except that "andar" is less formal).